# geocomplete - marker not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, geocomplete

Using http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/draggable.html as an example.

HTML:

```
<div id="addresses">
        <label>Address 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control geocomplete" id="addr_1" data-addrn="1" placeholder="Type your address here" value="" />
        <div class="map_canvas" id="addr_canvas_1"></div>
        <div id="addr_inf_1">
            <input type="hidden" data-geo-1="lat" placeholder="Latitude" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" data-geo-1="lng" placeholder="Longitude" value="" />
        </div>
```

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script src="jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
$("#addresses").find(".geocomplete").each(function() {
    var $cElem = $(this);
    var $addrNum = $cElem.data("addrn");
    $cElem.geocomplete({
      map: "#addr_canvas_"+$addrNum,
      details: "#addr_inf_1"+$addrNum,
      detailsAttribute: "data-geo-"+$addrNum,
      markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
      }
    });
});});
```

The problem is that its displaying the map but not the marker. Why?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line of css was the reason of blocking the marker on map

div { max-height:999%;}